# FastMM log to file without FullDebugMode

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, fastmm

I'd like to get FastMM memory leak report that shows up on app shutdown, but in a file instead of the dialog box. The idea is to use it in a release build as I have trouble reproducing the leaks.
I would however prefer to not use the FullDebugMode which seems to be required for logging to a file.

Am I missing anything or is this not supported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From FastMM4.pas:

```
  {Error logging requires FullDebugMode}
  {$undef LogErrorsToFile}
```

So, yes logging to a file is only available in FullDebugMode as the intent was to get the details of the leaks, not the summary only which you get normally in the MessageBox.

You have to modify yourself FastMM4.pas to allow logging of the summary to a file when the `NoMessageBoxes` option is set.

Another option you might want to look at is the `UseOutputDebugString`. It allows to send the FastMM messages to a DebugView Window. (DbgView from SysInternals for instance)